# Codeigniter : Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem in link of my script by Codeigniter. I have this URL :-

localhost/index.php/admin/orders/
Its get me all order of product, But when i add any character in the end of link like this :

localhost/index.php/admin/orders/ggg
The user see some error message.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in
```

How can save my link, And hidden this message.

My Controller :-

```
function orders()
{
    $data['orders'] = $this->admin_model->getOrderList();
    $data['total']  = $this->admin_model->getOrderCount();
    $this->load->view('admin/orders',$data);
}
```

My Model:-

```
 function getOrderList()
{
    $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
    if($page=='')
        $page=1;

    $start = ($page-1)*RECORDS_PER_PAGE;
    $end = RECORDS_PER_PAGE;

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->limit($end,$start);

    $this->db->order_by('order_id','DESC');
    $result = $this->db->get('wg_orders');
    if($result->num_rows()>0)
    return $result->result();
    else
    return 'empty';
}
```

Comment: Include your full error message.

Comment: it should not be.There must be something after `on a non-object in `like line numbers and where.

Comment: however use `$page=intval($this->uri->segment(3);)` because you getting string `ggg` as page number which is wrong and you getting query error.

Comment: so what can i do . in this case i need to show error 404

Comment: check `$this->uri->segment(3);` if it is not a number call `show_404();`

Comment: in every case you can test that `$result` is not null

Comment: How can i check it please tell me

Comment: `if($result = $this->db->get('wg_orders')) { do smthg } else { query error }`

Comment: i return 'empty' man but show same error

Comment: $result may be not object only if it false. In this case you will execute else part of code.

Comment: Try using `count_all_results()` instead of `num_rows()`

Comment: its show `Call to a member function count_all_results() on a non-objec`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count()` function as well.

In Controller

```
    function orders()
    {
        $data['orders'] = $this->admin_model->getOrderList();
        $data['total']  = $this->admin_model->getOrderCount();
        $this->load->view('admin/orders',$data);
    }
```

In Model

```
    function getOrderList()
    {
        $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
        if($page=='')
            $page=1;

        $start = ($page-1)*RECORDS_PER_PAGE;
        $end = RECORDS_PER_PAGE;

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (your_argument) LIMIT $end, $start ORDER BY order_id DESC ");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $count = count($result);

        if($count>0)
        {
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return 'empty';
        }
    }
```